# Position Fancybox 2 manually

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I can not for the life of me, figure out how I can reposition Fancybox 2 to use `left: 47px;` and `top: 147px`

I read through the source code, and without hacking it, I don't see a way to override the positioning.

Setting `autoCenter` to false only stops auto-centering after the *first* time it does it.

Using jQuery to change the CSS, or giving a custom wrapper to apply the CSS doesn't work either, because Fancybox always adds inline CSS which overwrites all my attempts.

Is there a way to tell Fancybox to stop positioning itself and to use my absolute positioning?

Comment: You can probably do it with the poorly documented `helpers:` option.  I'd post it as an answer if I could find the exact code.

Comment: I'm not finding anything.  I don't think what you want to do is an option without editing the source code of the plugin.  If you're going to do that, you might as well simply add your additional positioning options so at least the plugin remains scalable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [override inline CSS](http://powers1.net/css-override-inline-styles) styles using the `!important` modifier.

For the Fancybox use case the following will override the JavaScript positioning:

```
.fancybox-wrap { 
  top: 147px !important; 
  left: 47px !important; 
}
```

Comment: That gets overwritten by the inline CSS that Fancybox 2 injects using jQuery's css().

Comment: That's odd - the `!important` should override any inline style, including styles set with `css()` - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/YKhEG/ - maybe `#fancybox-wrap` is the wrong selector?

Comment: That's what it is: it's .fancybox-wrap. You're correct, that's all I needed. Thank you!

Comment: This works great for me when I hardcode the css as shown, but I need to dynamically position the popup. When I try to dynamically set the positioning like this `$(".fancybox-wrap").css("top", "5px");` it seems to get set, but is ignored. If I add the !important modifier to it, it doesn't even seem to get set. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by adding manually a new css-class in the beforeShow-Handler. I used fancybox2.

css:

```
.fancybox-wrap22 {
  top: 22% !important;
}
```

js:

```
$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {
  $.fancybox.open('<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>', {
    beforeShow : function() {
      $('.fancybox-wrap').addClass('fancybox-wrap22');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution for fancybox2. You can override the default _getPosition method to prevent one or more dimensions being altered.

```
// Disable vertical repositioning
var orig = $.fancybox._getPosition;
$.extend($.fancybox, {
    _getPosition: function(onlyAbsolute) {
        var rez = orig(onlyAbsolute);
        delete rez.top;
        return rez;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. How would you get this to position fancybox over the top of the trigger element and slightly offset to the right by 20px?  And what does `onlyAbsolute` mean in your code example?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you change the css like so?
Obviously changing the margin property to 'top' and 'left'

```
$("a.fancybox1").fancybox({
 'hideOnContentClick': false,
         'onComplete'    :   function() {
            $("#fancybox-wrap").css('margin', 'auto');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't change the css in that way, cause the fancybox core is editing the style property of #fancybox-wrap all the time. So you must add a new class, like in my example described. Otherwise you won't see any visuell changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem -- I want to position a fancybox manually but it keeps re-centering automatically.

I solved it disabling the center function:

```
$.fancybox.center = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucas Teixeira was right! This worked for me. First turn off center function then use onComplete event to set inline css as you wish.

```
   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            //turn off center function
            $.fancybox.center = function () { };

            //use onComplete event to modify inline css 
            $("#ModalPopup").fancybox({
                'modal': true,
                'onComplete': function () {
                    $("#fancybox-wrap").css({ 'left': '250px', 'top': '150px' });
                }
            });

        });
   </script>
```