# How to disable automatic centering of a Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

First of all, this is my first post here on stackoverflow so correct me if I'm wrong at something.

I have a problem using Fancybox, I am using Fancybox v2.1.5.
As you may know Fancybox automaticly centers your fancybox to position it in the middle of the screen.
I actually need my fancybox to be positioned on a specific amount of pixels from the left and the top of the screen (these values are variable and change when the window resizes, this is the reason why I thought CSS only wouldn't be the solution).

I wrote a small piece of JavaScript code to make sure the fancybox would stay in the correct position but apparently the Fancybox plugin has it's own kind of script to make sure the fancybox is centered. As you'd imagine, these two pieces of code conflict with eachother making the fancybox jumping from the right position to the centered position.

**So my question is, how can I make sure Fancybox won't center my fancybox so I can use my own piece of code to position the fancybox?**

If you're interested, this is the code I use to position my fancybox:

```
var position = "";
var position_interval = setInterval(function() { 
    if ($('#module1').offset().left != position.left)
    {
        $('.social_fancybox').css($('#module1').offset());
        position = $('#module1').offset();
    }
    if ($('.social_fancybox').length < 1)
    {
        clearInterval(position_interval);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Which version of Fancybox are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I use Fancybox v2.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox 2.5 has a few parameters you want to have a look at.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    'topRatio':0,
    'leftRatio':0
});
```

So with those two parameters you can set the amount the popup has to be from the top/left.
Default is `0.5` which places the popup in the middle of the screen.

Alternatively you could call the `afterShow` function, which is triggered as soon as the popup is shown. In that function you could specify where you want the popup to be.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Thanks. As you can see in my original post (edited), I'm using a variable amount of pixels from the left and top. These values change when the browser's window resizes. Wouldn't I still be having the same issue with the two positions conflicting eachother when using this approach? It's a pity these parameters only accept percentages instead of pixels.

Comment: Additionally there is a callback function `onUpdate` which is triggered whenever the window is resized or scrolled.

Comment: If I would re-position the fancybox in this `onUpdate` event, don't you think this still conflicts with Fancybox's automatic center mechanism making the fancybox jump from one position to the other again? (No idea why your answer got a downvote, don't understand why my question got a downvote either.)

Comment: No it doesn't do that.

Comment: Looks like you're right. It seems to be working just fine without any jumping positions, thank you! I don't think it'd be possible to make this event fire any faster, would it? It looks like the event only gets fired at a maximum of 4 or 5 times a second which could make the animations of the fancybox look a bit choppy. (Accepted your answer)

Comment: No not without changing the actual fancybox plugin.

Comment: Alright, that's what I wanted to know. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

You could add a CSS rule that uses the `!important` modifier. This overrules every other CSS rule for that element, e.g.:

```
p {color:red !important;}
p {color:blue;}
```

The `p` will have red text.

To apply this to your fancybox, use the following:

```
.fancybox-wrap {
    top:100px !important; /* or whatever you choose */
    left:100px !important; /* or whatever you choose */
}
```

More: [Position Fancybox 2 manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932296/position-fancybox-2-manually)

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you could manually set the Fancybox's position using jQuery;

```
$('.fancybox-wrap').css('top',yourTopValue);
$('.fancybox-wrap').css('left',yourLeftValue);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. The problem is I am using variable positions. I don't think this would be possible using CSS only, would it? I already read something about the !important tag in combination with my problem, but since the position of the fancybox would be variable I thought this wouldn't be possible using CSS only.

Comment: You can use jQuery to dynamically update the element's CSS position values - see my edit.

Comment: I know, that's what I am doing right here: `$('.social_fancybox').css($('#module1').offset());` When using this approach, Fancybox keeps conflicting with this piece of code trying to center the fancybox while this line of code tries to position it on another location.

Comment: Ah, I must have misunderstood, sorry. To be honest, putvande's answer looks the best. You could also look into manipulating a document's style sheet rules using JavaScript ( https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=manipulate+stylesheet+javascript&oq=manipulate+styleshert+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-GB&espv=1) as this will allow you to override using `!important`.

Comment: No problem. You seem to be right, it looks like putvande's answer is the best solution to my problem. Thanks for your answer, though!